# EmberJs - Is there a way to tell ember to insert the main-view after the rootElement?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi I would like to know if the is a way to tell ember to initialize immediately after the root Element?

For example I have this DOM Structure:

```
<div id="#bodyContent" class="ember-application">
   <div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">
   </div>
   <div id="ember357" class="ember-view">
   </div>
</div>
```

But I Want ember to be first on the DOM:

```
<div id="#bodyContent" class="ember-application">
   <div id="ember357" class="ember-view">
   </div>
   <div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">
   </div>
</div>
```

In my enviroment.js file I have this line:

```
ENV.APP.rootElement = "#bodyContent";
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember uses `appendTo` to insert it's view inside root element. But you could override [`didCreateRootView`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/62a54fd0e54cddbc7d3ab2d710dd6a63b9e92aa1/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application-instance.js#L139-L153) of ember instance and change it to use `prependTo`. Have a look how [Fastboot does this](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/blob/master/app/instance-initializers/browser/clear-double-boot.js).

Update: This is an instance-initializer to overwrite `didCreateRootView`.

```
export function initialize(appInstance) {
  appInstance.didCreateRootView = function(view) {
    // overwrite didCreateRootView
  };
}

export default {
  name: 'prepend-to',
  initialize
};
```

ember/glimmer does not provide an `prependTo` method. You have to implement that one on your own following the implementation of `appendTo`.

Please also note that `didCreateRootView` is a private hook. Don't expect that one to keep stable over time.

In general I would not recommend to go this path if there is any other way to achieve your goal. Please consider adding a container for ember at desired position. If you don't have control over HTML markup you might could add a container using jQuery before initializing ember.

Update 2:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

export function initialize(appInstance) {
  appInstance.didCreateRootView = function(view) {
    let containerId = 'ember-container';
    jQuery('<div>').prop('id', containerId).prependTo(jQuery(this.rootElement));
    view.appendTo(`#${containerId}`);
  };
}

export default {
  name: 'prepend-to',
  initialize
};
```

This is not exactly what you've asked for but it's much easier to achieve. If your HTML markup looks like `<body><div id="existing-content"></body>` and body as default root element above instance initializer will add another div `#ember-container` before `#existing-content` and using this one as embers root element.

Update 3: 
You find an ember-twiddle here: https://ember-twiddle.com/43cfd1ae978b810f2e7cf445f9a3d40c?openFiles=instance-initializers.root-element.js%2C

If you inspect DOM you will see that ember root element is wrapped by `<div id="ember-container"></div>`. This wrapper is append to `rootElement`. So it's before any existing content in `rootElement`. I guess it's not possible to define a custom `index.html` in ember-twiddle so I can't demonstrate this one. But you could easily test yourself.

Comment: @DeividKamui updated my answer with more example code and note about a much easier approach which might be acceptable for you.

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: Does not work the initializer didCreateRootView is never called I've added a console.info inside the function to check the execution but does not print the message in the console.

Comment: I've tested in a newly generated ember-cli project using 2.11.0. This must be an integration error on your side. Please not that we are talking about instance-initializer I'm not sure if it also works with "normal" initializers.

Comment: Could please share a twiddle?

Comment: Provided an ember-twiddle.